# jQuery Update and Scroll like Polling

Tags: jquery, ajax, polling

Looking for something written in jQuery which allows polling or a plugin which would allow data updates similar to [this website](http://www.hollrr.com).

Anyone got any ideas of something like this in jQuery ? Or how to write something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the div first with display none using preepend() function. And then for the slide animation use $("#div-1").slideToggle("slow");

For update your list you can set an ajax function to check periodically with setInterval() javascript function and call prepend function with the new line.